# Intercept event when combobox edited

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm using a `ComboBox` as part of a larger GUI, written in python/tkinter.

When the drop-down selection is changed, the color is updated to indicate to the user that something has changed.

However, the combobox also allows the user to type in their own value.  **I also want the color to change when this happens.**

The problem is, I don't see anything in [the `ComboBox` documentation](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/ttk_combobox.htm) indicating how to do this.

Comment: I guess you'll need a combination of traces and validation to get the exact effect you want. More tricky will be persuading the combobox to like your color changes; style hacking is ill-documented, alas.

Comment: @DonalFellows -- true; I could never get any style changes to work until I started using "wrapped" super-widgets that put built-in widgets like comboboxes and checkbuttons in their own frames.  Then I can just change the color, or anything else, of the frame.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I noticed that somewhere in Python's `Tkinter` docs, it mentions that `Combobox` is a subclass of `Entry`.

With an `Entry`, here's what you do.  Set the configuration:

- `-validatecommand` should be set to the thing that you want to happen when a key is pressed (in my case, change a color).
- `-validate` should be set to `key`, meaning that the validation command will be called whenever a key is pressed while the cursor is in the entry.

[Here's](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/ttk_entry.htm) the tk page on text entries for further reference.

Doing the exact same thing for comboboxes works just the same way (as far as I can tell).

Answer (score 15):

You can use a StringVar as a parameter of the Combobox constructor. This StringVar can be traced (*ie*, subscribe to each change).

Here a small example:

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *

def on_field_change(index, value, op):
    print "combobox updated to ", c.get()

root = Tk()
v = StringVar()
v.trace('w',on_field_change)
c = Combobox(root, textvar=v, values=["foo", "bar", "baz"])
c.pack()

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 8):

Just bind `'<<ComboboxSelected>>'` to a method...

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Main(tk.Tk):
     
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    self.container = tk.Frame(self)
    self.container.pack(side="top", fill = "both", expand=True)
    self.container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.cb=ttk.Combobox(self.container, values=[0,1, 2, 3] , state='readonly')
    self.cb.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', self.modified)    
    self.cb.pack()
                  
  def modified (self, event) :
      print(self.cb.get())
    
main = Main()
main.mainloop()
```